# How to return a Python Object via Jinja2 back to Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Couldn't find any question related to this issue. I'm probably doing it the wrong way because I'm sure there must be an easier way to achieve this, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

--> I'm trying to get a Python object from Jinja2 back to Python, so I can access its values back in Python.

So I'm passing an array of users from Python(Flask) to a drop-down in HTML which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user">
        {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user }}">{{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }} 
            ({{ user.birthdate }})</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

This works perfectly and I can select a user in the dropdown. Now I want to access the users user.address attributes back in Python. (of course these attributes are already defined in the user class).

So I have a function like this in Python (Flask) which gets triggered when pressing a button:

```
@app.route("/display_user", methods=["POST"])
def display_user():

    user = request.form["user"] 
    address = user.address
    return render_template("show.html", address=address)
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'address'".

I'm getting back the json as a string which looks like this:

```
{'firstname': 'test','lastname': 'test','birthday': 'test','address': 'test'}
```

I should now probably create a dict out of this string/json and then access these values with ['address'], but somehow I couldn't figure out how. I tried it with json.dumps() which did not work, still the same error message. Also I figured there must be an easier/better way to achieve this.

Any suggestions? (using Python 3.6.2)

Comment: that's not json by the way, that's a python [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

Comment: okay, I see now. thanks! is there a way to go from a repr back to an instance of that class? or make Jinja2 return the instace/json of the user?

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I ended up with this solution:

I only returned the ._id and not the whole instance of the user as follows:

**Jinja2/HTML:**

```
<option value="{{ user._id }}">{{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname}} ({{ user.birthdate }})</option>
```

Then I just did a new query for the user in my database (I'm using MongoDB) using  its _id.

**Python 3.6:**

```
user_id = request.form["user"]
user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
```

And then I could access it's attributes with `user.address` and so on. Works fine, but I'm not quite happy with the solution since I need to query the database again.

So if anyone has a different approach, I'm glad to hear it :-)

Comment: This is probably the best situation, otherwise someone could just forge the object clientside.

Comment: ok thanks for your input :) I will stick with this solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you get back json as a string you can use json.loads.

```
import json
values = json.loads('{"firstname": "test","lastname": "test","birthday": "test","address": "test"}')
print(values["firstname"])
```

This will output test. Please note that the string you posted is not Json. JSON strings must use double quotes.

Comment: okay, that explains why it doesn't work. looks like I'm not getting back a json but the repr of the object. i could replace all ' with " but that doesn't seem like the best solution..